# ping of wifi goes down when I disconnect eth0 cable

Tags: wireless-networking, ping

I have some trouble with my Orange Pi wifi connection.

My distrib is a Orange Pi ubuntu server 16.04.

When I ping wlan0 ip address, it works only if I add the eth0 cable connected.
When I unplugged it, both eth0 ip ping and wlan0 ip ping stop to respond.

What I have noticed also is that there's no route for my pc through wlan0.
So I think that my ping goes back from my pi through the eth0 interface.

I have tried to add a route through wlan0 with a higher metric but it doesn't seems to be better. When I unplugged both goes down.

I have configure my `/etc/network/interfaces` file as is :

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# wired network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

# wireless network interface
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-ssid "my_ssid"
wpa-psk "my_pwd"
```

When I do `arp -a` on my PC, I have :

```
Interface : 192.168.0.24 --- 0x8
Adresse Internet      Adresse physique      Type
192.168.0.36          f6-6d-bf-6f-1c-04     dynamique
192.168.0.47          f6-6d-bf-6f-1c-04     dynamique
192.168.0.254         f4-ca-e5-5e-b2-37     dynamique
```

Please, note the same MAC address for both ip eth0 and ip wlan0.

When I do `ifconfig` on my orange pi, I have :

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f6:6d:bf:6f:1c:04
          inet addr:192.168.0.36  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: 2a01:e35:8ab3:590:f46d:bfff:fe6f:1c04/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::f46d:bfff:fe6f:1c04/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:821 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:672 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:68083 (68.0 KB)  TX bytes:58029 (58.0 KB)
          Interrupt:114

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f4:6d:bf:6f:1c:05
          inet addr:192.168.0.47  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: 2a01:e35:8ab3:590:f064:ea1c:6039:579a/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: 2a01:e35:8ab3:590:f66d:bfff:fe6f:1c05/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::f66d:bfff:fe6f:1c05/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:135 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:12 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:26368 (26.3 KB)  TX bytes:1621 (1.6 KB)
```

When I do `route` on my orange pi, I have :

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.0.254   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
```

Comment: your link encapsulation on wlan0 is listed as an ethernet connection - I don't know exactly how to resolve it, but the computer thinks the wlan0 is an ethernet connection. Also note that eth0 and wlan0 do NOT have the same physical address - ifconfig displays that they both have different HWaddresses.